# Event only fires once when making Ajax request in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, spservices

I have a couple of drop downs that are populated from SharePoint using SPServices. This part works great. But then, I have a button that on click loads data from SharePoint and uses the dropdown texts as filter to fetch the data that will populate a table using the DataTables plugin. This part works only once; if I click the button again, nothing happens.

This is how I populate the dropdowns:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var theYear; // Selected Year
var theRO; // Selected RO
//Fills the Dropdown lists (Year and RO)
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "{ListID}",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Fiscal_x0020_Year' /><FieldRef    Name='Regional_x0020_Office' /></ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //Add Select Value option
        $("#dropdown").prepend($('<option>', {
            value: '',
            text: 'Select Fiscal Year'
        }));
        $("#dropdownRO").prepend($('<option>', {
            value: '',
            text: 'Select Regional Office'
        }));
        //Fetching Data from SharePoint    
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {
            var dropDown = "<option value='" + $(this).attr("ows_Fiscal_x0020_Year") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Fiscal_x0020_Year") + "</option>";
            var dropDownRO = "<option value='" + $(this).attr("ows_Regional_x0020_Office") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Regional_x0020_Office") + "</option>";
            $("#dropdown").append(dropDown);
            $("#dropdownRO").append(dropDownRO);
            /////////////Deletes duplicates from dropdown list////////////////
            var usedNames = {};
            $("#dropdown > option, #dropdownRO > option").each(function () {
                if (usedNames[this.text]) {
                    $(this).remove();
                } else {
                    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
                }
            });
            ////Deletes repeated rows from table
            var seen = {};
            $('#myTable tr, #tasksUL li, .dropdown-menu li').each(function () {
                var txt = $(this).text();
                if (seen[txt]) $(this).remove();
                else seen[txt] = true;
            });
        });
    } //end of completeFunc
}); //end of SPServices
$('.myButton').on('click', function () {
    run()
});
}); //End jQuery Function
```

This is the function I need to run every time I click on "myButton" after changing my selection in the dropdowns:

```
        function run() {

theYear = $('#dropdown option:selected').text(); // Selected Year
theRO = $('#dropdownRO option:selected').text(); // Selected RO
var call = $.ajax({
    url: "https://blah-blah-blah/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Consolidated%20LC%20Report')/items()?$filter=Fiscal_x0020_Year%20eq%20'" + theYear + "' and Regional_x0020_Office eq '" + theRO + "'&$orderby=Id&$select=Id,Title,Fiscal_x0020_Year,Notices_x0020_Received,Declined_x0020_Participation,Selected_x0020_Field_x0020_Revie,Selected_x0020_File_x0020_Review,Pending,Pending_x0020_Previous_x0020_Yea,Controversial,GFP_x0020_Reviews,NAD_x0020_Appeals,Mediation_x0020_Cases,Monthly_x0020_Cost_x0020_Savings,Monthly_x0020_Expenditure,Regional_x0020_Office,Month_Number", //Works, filters added
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    }
}); //End of ajax function///
call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
            [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
        ],
            "iDisplayLength": -1, //Number of rows by default. -1 means All Records
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaData": data.d.results,
            "bJQueryUI": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [{
            "mData": "Id",
            "bVisible": false
        }, //Invisible column
        {
            "mData": "Title"
        }, {
            "mData": "Notices_x0020_Received"
        }, {
            "mData": "Declined_x0020_Participation"
        }, {
            "mData": "Selected_x0020_Field_x0020_Revie"
        }, {
            "mData": "Selected_x0020_File_x0020_Review"
        }, {
            "mData": "Pending"
        }, {
            "mData": "Pending_x0020_Previous_x0020_Yea"
        }, {
            "mData": "Controversial"
        }, {
            "mData": "GFP_x0020_Reviews"
        }, {
            "mData": "NAD_x0020_Appeals"
        }, {
            "mData": "Mediation_x0020_Cases"
        }, {
            "mData": "Monthly_x0020_Cost_x0020_Savings",
            "fnRender": function (obj, val) {
                return accounting.formatMoney(val);
            }
        }, {
            "mData": "Monthly_x0020_Expenditure",
            "fnRender": function (obj, val) {
                return accounting.formatMoney(val);
            }
        }],
            "bDeferRender": true,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
            "sDom": 'T&;"clear"&;frtip',
            "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": ["xls"],
                "sSwfPath": "../../Style Library/js/datatables/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        },
            "sSearch": "Filter",
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            //Add totals row
            var Columns = $("#example > tbody").find("> tr:first > td").length;
            $('#example tr:last').after('<tr><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td><td  class="total"></td></tr>');
            //Formating the Total row number to no decimals
            $("#example tr:last td:not(:first,:last)").text(function (i) {
                var t = 0;
                $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (i + 2) + ")").each(function () {
                    t += parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1);
                });
                return parseInt(t * 100, 10) / 100;
            });
            //Format the monthly expenditure and savings to currency formatFormating the currency
            var cell = new Array();
            cell[0] = $('#example tr:last td:nth-child(12)').text();
            cell[1] = $('#example tr:last td:nth-child(13)').text();
            $('#example tr:last').find('td:nth-child(12)').html(accounting.formatMoney(cell[0]));
            $('#example tr:last').find('td:nth-child(13)').html(accounting.formatMoney(cell[1]));
            $('#example tr:last').find('td:last').hide();
        } //hides extra td that was showing
    }); //End of Datatable()
}); //End of call.done function
$('#theTableDiv').slideDown();
} //end of run() function
```

I'm not a programmer, I'm just trying to learn. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console? Assuming there wasn't a page refresh in between button clicks, the issue is likely your trying to initialize DataTables against an element (#example) that it's already initialized on. If this is the case, you'll see an error in the console confirming that. The proper approach, if DataTables has already been initialized, is to use their API to update the existing table then refresh it via .draw()  http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29

Comment: Thanks Stevangelista! I don't get any error at all. I think you are right, it seems to be DataTables the one giving me the headaches. I tried draw(), drawCallback(), etc, etc, and no luck. I was getting so close to achieve what I had in mind.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery AJAX? [It has it's own AJAX capabilities](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) so you don't have to reinitialize.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are replacing the part of the page where the button lives. (you really need to format your code more neatly for SO... use JSFiddle.net and their TidyUp button).

If that is the case you need to use a *delegated event handler*:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myButton', function () {
    run()
});
```

This listens at a static ancestor of the desired node, *then* runs the selector when the event occurs, *then* it applies the function to any matching elements that caused the event.

`document` is the fallback parent if you don't have a convenient ancestor. Do not use 'body' for delegated events as it has odd behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestion and the TidyUp tool (very useful by the way). But your solution doesn't work. As suggested by Stevangelista, the issue is the DataTables plugin. Somehow I need to bind the draw() or drawCallback() function to my button, and so far no luck getting this done.

Comment: Shame. That answers 90% of *only works once* problems :) Please do apply the TidyUp as it is hard to read the code as it is formatted.